# .forEach inside of a Meteor Method can't get return

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor

I have a simple test, I have a Meteor method on the server side which is basically a variable that contains a collection let's say:

```
Meteor.methods({
usernames: function() {
 var test_users = Meteor.users.find();
 test_users.forEach(function (user) {
   console.log(user.username);
   return 'test output';
 });
}
})
```

If I try to to call this on the client side with Meteor call I can't ever get 'test output' but the console.log will work, I would've expected to get the first 'test output'... is this a asynchronous issue?

If I put a return 'something' after the .forEach loop it will return that..

Comment: I'm not sure what drivers Meteor uses, but generally I would think that Meteor.users.find() takes a callback, ...find(function(users){}

Comment: What do you want to return? return inside forEach doesn't work that way...

Comment: Try `var useNames = test_users.map(function(user){return user.username;});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return 'test output';` is returning from the anonymous function you pass to `forEach` and not the usernames function.

Assuming you want to get the list of usernames back, you probably to want use [`cursor.map`](http://docs.meteor.com/#map) like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
  usernames: function() {
    var test_users = Meteor.users.find();
    return test_users.map(function (user) {
      console.log(user.username);
      return user.username;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: ahhh, that was the part I was missing, it's returning from the anonymous function, not the usernames function. thanks again Oleg